# How to compose images in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, decorator, eclipse-plugin

This is a followup to [Items decorations in a TreeViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6263338/821436): I have a TreeView with my own Objects. I already have a `LabelProvider` that supplies Icons and Texts. Now I want to decorate the images with other images depending on some conditions. How can I do this? The referenced question uses `ComposedImage`, which I suppose is `org.eclipse.emf.edit.provider`.

Is there a way to do this with SWT/JFace in Eclipse 4.3?

I already tried using a `ILightweightLabelDecorator` (using the idea from the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_label_decorations_to_my_viewer?)), but gave up wrapping that round my `LabelProvider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ILightweightLabelDecorator` is really the best way to do this. Wrap your label provider with a DecoratingLabelProvider as described in this answer: [Using a ILightweightLabelDecorator decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161651/using-a-ilightweightlabeldecorator-decorator)  Use the `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` extension point to declare your lightweight decorator.

Comment: So although `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager().getLabelDecorator())` returns an `ILabelDecorator` I can use an `ILightweightLabelDecorator` in the extension point?

Comment: Yes the decorator manager returns a label decorator which manages the lightweight decorators (you can have several if you wish).

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look at   `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecorationOverlayIcon` which is basically used by decoration providers.